# codeigniter: get percentage in multiple table by data category

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

I have tables like this,

```
table_a

PID  Name   Type
1    a      selling
2    b      sampling
3    c      selling
4    d      sampling
5    e      selling
```

And,

```
table_b

ID      PID   Qty
1       2     3
2       2     2
3       1     1
4       3     1
5       1     3
6       5     3
7       4     3
8       3     2
```

I need to show like this,

```
output_selling

Name           Total_qty     Percentage
a              4             40%
c              3             30%
e              3             30%
```

And,

```
output_sampling

Name           Total_qty     Percentage
b              5             62,5%
d              3             37,5%
```

How would I go about this in CodeIgniter?

Comment: `function output_selling(){
    $total = $this->db->select('SUM(table_b.Qty) as Total_qty', FALSE); 
    $this->db->select('((sum(table_b.Qty)/'.$total.',0)*100 )as percentage', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('table_b');
    $this->db->join('table_a', 'table_a.PID= table_b.PID', 'left');
    $this->db->where('table_a.Type', "selling");
    $this->db->group_by('table_b.PID');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use below in your function and change 'sampling' and 'selling' as you need it:

```
$this->db->query("
SELECT dd.NAME, 
       dd.total_qty, 
       ( dd.total_qty / dd.totals ) * 100 AS Percentage 
FROM   (SELECT a.NAME, 
               Sum(b.qty)                            AS Total_qty, 
               (SELECT Sum(b1.qty) AS total 
                FROM   table_b b1 
                       JOIN table_a a1 
                         ON a1.pid = b1.pid 
                            AND a1.type = 'selling') AS totals 
        FROM   table_a a 
               JOIN table_b b 
                 ON b.pid = a.pid 
                    AND a.type = 'selling' 
        GROUP  BY a.pid) dd ");
```

Please see below query output:

[image]